# MVC controller returns JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this HTML and script :

```
<form>
    Text :<br>
    <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form> 

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/MyController/MyAction2",
           data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
            success: function (newdata) {
                var cy = cytoscape({
                    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
                    elements: JSON.parse(newdata)

                });
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```

When `MyAction2` is called from AJAX, the url goes to `MyAction2` and I see raw JSON data. How can I make `MyAction2` returns value to the AJAX and I would use it as `newdata` variable? Thanks.

Comment: What is `newdata`? An object? A variable? Try using the console window to debug the `success` from the AJAX and view the content of `newdata`

Comment: @Sandman As I understand this common issue: it's not returning the ajax method but instead showing the JSON data directly in the browser ("I see raw JSON data").

Comment: Change the input to a button instead of submit: `<input type='button' value='Send'>` and handle click rather than submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've used to get JSON data is correct, you just need to stop the form submission, which you can do by calling `preventDefault()` on the event.

Also note that you have a mis-matched `});` in the question but I assume this is just a typo in the question itself. Also note that you don't need to manually `JSON.parse` the response if you set the correct `dataType`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // < add this...

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/MyController/MyAction2",
      data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function (newdata) {
        var cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById("cy"),
          elements: newdata
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: return false in the end of the eventhandler might be help

Comment: @mr.void that's basically the same as `preventDefault()` except it stops propagation too.

Comment: There is no error. I think there is an error related to cytoscape.js. Thank you very much.